# uWSGI worker respawning although the request is not yet finished

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I wrote a flask app based on this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04)

My application behaves like a kind of file-distributor. It accepts files and distributes them to different APIs on other systems.

Sometimes I see the following error in the nginx error log.

```
2019/11/06 14:01:01 [error] 28912#28912: *19810346 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.2.60, server: my.host.local, request: "POST /file/add HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/var/my_project/myproject.sock:", host: "my.host.local"
```

I turned on uWSGI logging and observed that when uWSGI is respawning its workers after 60 seconds, the error in the nginx log also appears. This does not happen all the time but in most cases (~90%) its like that. Sometimes it just works so I think, this must be a timing issue or something like that.

If I am right with my guess, an increase in worker life should reduce the number of error events in the nginx log. Actually, uWSGI shouldn't just respawn the worker while the request isn't finished so what is the problem?

uWSGI ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 48
threads = 2
enable-threads = True

limit-as = 512

disable-logging = True
buffer-size = 65535
max-worker-lifetime = 60

socket = myproject.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true

#location of log files
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

My app is running on a Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS virtual machine with 24 CPUs and 128GB RAM (I know it might be an overkill but its just for testing.)

Answer (score 2):

As `uwsgi` is respawning its workers, it seems like the `harakiri` timeout is being triggered.

`harakiri` mode makes `uwsgi` to respawn the worker process if the relevant response is taking more than *harakiri_seconds*, you can give it a bigger timeout e.g.:

```
harakiri = 120  # 2 mins
```

But you really should check which endpoint is taking so long to respond, 60 seconds for a web service to send any response is already too much.

---

Also note that, Nginx [`ngx_http_uwsgi_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html) also has different timeout parameters for different parts of request-response cycle, but from the error message the error seemed to be related to the upstream (`uwsgi`). But for your own understanding, you can take a look at the relevant directives there as well.